# How to mock @Inject Api-Class with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test a Java method with Junit,

Unfortunately I can't get any further at one point because the Api class was defended as @Inject

I actually tried everything I could, unfortunately ***null*** is always returned and the test fails every time.

```
    @Inject
    private MemberAPi memberApi;




    NewMember newMember = new NewMember();
    newMember = MemberApi.addMember(new CreateMemberParameterObj (newMember, getId , false, Obj ))
```

Test: I try to mock it like that e.g.

```
   @Mock
    private MemberAPi mockedMemberApi;



    when(mockedMemberAPi.addMember(anyObject())).thenReturn(anyObject());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mock the MemberAPI and the NewMember classes.
Use `@InjectMocks` and Mockito will automatically inject the mockMemberAPI object.

Here is some code:

```
@InjectMocks
private Blam classToTest; // your class.

@Mock
private MemberAPi mockMemberAPi;

@Mock
private NewMember mockNewMember;

@Before
public void before()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

    doReturn(mockNewMember).when(mockMemberAPI).addMember(anyObject());
}
```

I use the `doReturn().when().xxx();`
pattern instead of the
`when(mockedMemberAPi.addMember(anyObject())).thenReturn(mockMemberAPI);`
pattern.

Note:
`thenReturn(anyObject());` makes no sense because you can't return `anyObject()`.